# Is this stratified k-CV with caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to know how to program stratified k-CV by only using the caret package in R. See the example that follows:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data(Sonar)

set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]


folds <- createFolds(factor(training$Class), k = 10, list = TRUE)

fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
method = "cv",
indexOut=folds,
savePredictions="all")

set.seed(825)
gbmFit1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
             method = "gbm", 
             trControl = fitControl,
             ## This last option is actually one
             ## for gbm() that passes through
             verbose = FALSE)

d=gbmFit1$pred
```

Note that I am not specifying `index` but only `indexOut`. Does caret train the model with the complement of `IndexOut` each time? By inspecting `d`, I could see that the rowIndex matches the definition of each fold, but how can I confirm that the training set each time is the complement of the elements in fold i?

Comment: createFolds does stratified folds by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this interesting because I use `caret` all the time and had never thought about this direct questions about `index` and `indexOut`.
The help docs under `?trainControl` say that `indexOut` if `NULL` will contain the unique set of samples not contained in `index` but doesn't state for the other way around. So I dug into `train.default` to find out what was going on. When you assign

```
fitControl = trainControl(..., indexOut = ...)
```

you can assert for yourself that `fitControl$index == NULL`. In the code for `train.default` there is a line (line 109 of function definition) which checks this condition and then uses (for "cv") `createFolds` with the argument `returnTrain = TRUE`. It does this without checking what you have set for `indexOut`.

There appears to be no other code relevant to `index` and `indexOut` within `train.default` for this particular scenario. Which suggest nothing guarantees that there is no intersection between `index$Fold01` and `indexOut$Fold01`.

We could examine this further

```
intersect(x$control$index$Fold01,x$control$indexOut$Fold01)
## [1]  12  18  33  34  53  58  67  95 109 111 115 120 137 143 156
```

which came from running your exact code in the question. So it would seem that `index` and `indexOut` are not a perfect complement of one another.

I would suggest the safest way going forward would be to specify `index` rather than `indexOut` to get the desired effect.